# $f$ is an entire function if $|f(z)|\geq e^\pi $, what can we say about $f$

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

$$|f(z)|\geq e^\pi, \frac{1}{|f(z)|}\leq \frac{1}{e^\pi}$$If $\frac{1}{|f(z)|}$ is entire we can conclude $f$ is constant, but is it entire?

Comment: Clearly $\frac{1}{|f(z)|}$ is not holomorphic so it is not entire.  But $\frac1{f(z)}$ (without the norm) is entire for the reason that $f(z)$ is non-zero anywhere.  In fact, any non-constant entire function can omit at most one value.  This is the little Picard theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $f$ is entire and it is never equal to $0$, $\frac1f$ is entire, and therefore you can deduce that it is constant. So, $f$ is constant.